# Rewrite the pagination links of the response header in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4

I have an apache conf that uses `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` like this:

```
ProxyPass /api/v1/ http://navigator:5000/
ProxyPassReverse /api/v1/ http://navigator:5000/
```

Response headers from the `navigator` service that use the `Location` field correctly get rewritten so:

```
http://navigator:5000/foo/bar
```

becomes

```
http://localhost/api/v1/foo/bar
```

But `ProxyPassReverse` doesn't support rewriting the `Link` field of the response header, which I use for pagination (much like e.g. https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination).

So when navigator responds with a header that has the `Link` set to:

```
<http://navigator:5000/foo/bar?fromid=5cebb4724662a700099a9e56>; rel="next"
```

It won't be rewritten into the expected:

```
<http://localhost/api/v1/foo/bar?fromid=5cebb4724662a700099a9e56>; rel="next"
```

I have not found any other apache module that would do the job, granted I'm no expert on server configuration. I know there are ways to rewrite html/xml links in the response body, but since this is in the header and doesn't really look like html-links, that solution doesn't seem to apply.

How would I get those links rewritten?

### Edit

Based on the suggested answer, I have the following config that almost does what I want:

```
Header edit Link "http://navigator:5000/" "/api/v1/"
```

The configuration is used for several hosts (as an example `staging.example.com`, `www.example.com` and `localhost:5000`) so I can't use a hard coded string.

I could probably leave the link without host specified as a relative link, but I would be most happy if the edit could insert the host used in the request.

I've attempted to have the rewrite part be `"%{HTTP_HOST}/api/v1/"`, `"%{HTTP_HOST}e/api/v1/"`, `"{%HTTP_HOST}s/api/v1/"` and `"$HTTP_HOST/api/v1/"` but none of them give the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Header" [directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax) and edit particular header.

And the directive will look like:

```
Header edit Link expr="/foo/bar" /api/v1/foo/bar
```

You you need to replace also `localhost` you can add one more directive

```
Header edit Link expr="localhost" your_host_name
```

To use hostname you can use variable `HTTP_HOST`

```
Header edit Link "http://navigator:5000/" "${HTTP_HOST}/rest_api/v1/"
```

Comment: I started digging based on your example. For some reason it doesn't do anything if I include `always` as you wrote. And I based on my experimentation I've gotten to: `Header edit Link "http://navigator:5000/" "%{HOST}e/rest_api/v1/"`, but `HOST` doesn't exist, that is don't know how to insert the host and port of the request in rewriting the response header

Comment: @MartinZackrisson, as your host (in returned header) is always localhost you can replace it adding one more Header directive. Will edit my answer

Comment: The conf is deployed for several hosts like `staging.example.com` and `www.example.com` so I would need to get the actual host used in the request, but otherwise `Header edit Link "navigator:5000" my_host_name` would have worked to rewrite that part.

Comment: @MartinZackrisson, try to use HTTP_HOST as variable

Comment: `%{HTTP_HOST}` gives syntax error. I think that `mod_headers` only support either `%{HTTP_HOST}s` or `%{HTTP_HOST}e` but both of those report as `null`, so I'm probably missing something basic here.

Comment: Have you try to use $HTTP_HOST? (instead of %HTTP_HOST)